# Installing google chrome on RHEL 5.3

Tags: google-chrome, installation, rhel-5

I am trying to install Google chrome on RHEL 5.3 but getting error as

```
Missing Dependency:
libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.3) is needed by
package
google-chrome-beta-4.0.249.43-34537.i386
(/root/Desktop/google-chrome-beta_current_i386.rpm)
Missing Dependency: xdg-utils is
needed by package
google-chrome-beta-4.0.249.43-34537.i386
(/root/Desktop/google-chrome-beta_current_i386.rpm)
Missing Dependency: lsb >= 3.2 is
needed by package
google-chrome-beta-4.0.249.43-34537.i386
(/root/Desktop/google-chrome-beta_current_i386.rpm)
```

When try to install lsb package , I get output as

```
[root@localhost softwares]# yum install redhat-lsb
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.i386 installed and not available
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Using rpmforge?

Comment: @John T: I just installed new release of rpmforge and its working now .. installing lsb thanks :) .. you can post it as a answer

Comment: For completeness sake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your version of [rpmforge](http://repoforge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this post: [How to install Google Chrome in RHEL 6, Fedora 14/15?](http://chankeypathak.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-rhel-6.html)